# For MySQL id 7 == 7PFWMH2, but it should not

Tags: mysql, sql

On the website, I have a search function. It should exact match, not using LIKE.
I have a problem with understanding. MySQL is fetching two results, but I need only one(the last one, because it's a match). I'm assuming that this is the problem with the request parameter format.

SQL Schema:
id  bigint(20) unsigned Auto Increment with Primary key

[screenshot of query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMQtz.png)

```
SELECT id, sku, serial FROM `products` WHERE `id` = '7PFWH2' OR `serial` = '7PFWMH2'
```

This request is returning two records, but I need only 1. It subtracts 7 from 7PFWH2 and returns the record with id 7. Please see the screenshot.

So should I filter and validate input data, or change something in DB config?

Answer (score 1):

Your column `id` is numeric. It makes no sense to compare it with the string `'7PFWH2'`. You are telling MySQL to comapre the number with the string. MySQL tries to convert the string to a number in order to make this comparison. And due to some weird design decision in MySQL, it doesn't throw an error telling you that `'7PFWH2'` is not a number, but just takes the number from the left side of the string. This is why you are getting the row with `id = 7`.

So, either:

```
SELECT id, sku, serial
FROM products 
WHERE serial = '7PFWMH2';
```

Or, if you merely confused the `id` column with the `sku` column:

```
SELECT id, sku, serial
FROM products 
WHERE serial = '7PFWMH2' OR sku = '7PFWMH2';
```

Comment: so yeah, I need to validate the input data first. 
Also, I have tried CAST(id as CHAR) which is working for me, but not sure how proper this is.

Comment: Yes, you can cast the ID to char, but then the ID will be considered the string '7'. You won't find it with 007 anymore, although it is the same number. If you are fine with it, okay. It is weird though, that you invoke a search on an ID. This is just a technical number used to identify a row in the database. Usually nothing a person working with an app would even know.